# Facebook profile-pic with SSL link

Tags: facebook, ssl

I have html code containing FB profile pictures/clicable and etc/.

Using

```
 fb:profile-pic and FB.XFBML.parse
```

I receive image url with HTTP. To have HTTPS I'm using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?return_ssl_resources=1
```

but have to generate code to make image clickable and add other attributes existing in fb-profile-pic.

I wrote this code 4 months ago.
Now I'm seeing fb:profile-pic is returning HTTPS link to image. Nothing is mentioned in FB documentation about change in behaviour/HTTP or HTTPS/.

Does anybody know about current state FB.XFBML.parse - secure or non secure links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the protocol of the returned profile picture URL is the same as the protocol used to request the image.

So https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture will return the SSL version of Mark’s profile picture, while http://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture will return an HTTP URL.

`return_ssl_resources` can be used with both, with value `0` for an HTTP and `1` for an HTTPS URL.

> Does anybody know about current state FB.XFBML.parse - secure or non secure links?

I think the JS SDK should be able to decide this automatically, based upon the protocol the embedding page was requested with.

Comment: Unfortunately 'parse' produces HTTP only. Even request is HTTPS.

Comment: The docs mention no parameter for that (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/profile-pic/), and this older question came to the same conclusion, http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7318048/in-https-mode-fb-xfbml-parse-on-fbprofile-pic-makes-http-links-to-images You could create a bug report though, and as FB to fix it.

Comment: Parser produces code with urls. The only way to fix it is to replace protocol, but this sucks :(